# transferOwnership on Upgradable Contract

Tags: erc-721, proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading

I try to use the Upgradable Contract and transferOwnership but i have an issue.

What i want to do :

- vers1 of my contract
- deployProxy vers1 (with user1 : become the owner)
- deployed
- transferOwnership with user1 to another user2 (works)
- vers2 of my contract (for testing no code update of the contract, deploy the same)
- upgradeProxy to vers2 (with user2 because he is the new owner) << issue

See my unit test below :

```
console.log('Before Change, Owner: ', await contract.owner()); // show user1 address
const transaction = await contract.transferOwnership(user2.address); // transfer to user2
const receipt = await transaction.wait();
console.log('After change, Owner: ', await contract.owner()); // show user2 address
const factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract", user2); // use user2 because is the new owner
const upgraded = await upgrades.upgradeProxy(contract.address, factory);
```

Always have : reverted with reason string 'Ownable: caller is not the owner' But the contract.owner() show the new user2

I think there is issue between implementation, proxy but i d'ont find the issue. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full contracts I can't tell whats going on but my guess would be to add ", {from: user2}" to your upgradeProxy call

Comment: Thanks, i tried but same issue.
The contract is almost empty

`
contract MyContract is ERC721Upgradeable, AccessControlUpgradeable, OwnableUpgradeable, EIP712Upgradeable{

    mapping (address => uint256) pendingWithdrawals;
    mapping (uint256 => uint256) minted;
    function initialize() initializer public {
        __ERC721_init("Test", "test");
        __ERC721URIStorage_init();
        __AccessControl_init();
        __Ownable_init();
    }
`

Comment: this issue come from this method in "Ownable" :

    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }

owner() => user2 (the good new owner)
_msgSender() => user1 (the old owner)